# FreqDist using NLTK

Tags: python, frequency, nltk, frequency-distribution

I'm trying to get a frequency distribution of a set of documents using Python.  My code isn't working for some reason and is producing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\aschein\Desktop\freqdist", line 32, in <module>
    fd = FreqDist(corpus_text)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 104, in __init__
    self.update(samples)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 472, in update
    self.inc(sample, count=count)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 120, in inc
    self[sample] = self.get(sample,0) + count
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can you help?

This is the code so far:

```
import os
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist


#The stop=words list
stopwords_doc = open("C:\\Documents and Settings\\aschein\\My Documents\\stopwords.txt").read()
stopwords_list = stopwords_doc.split()
stopwords = nltk.Text(stopwords_list)

corpus = []

#Directory of documents
directory = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\aschein\\My Documents\\comments"
listing = os.listdir(directory)

#Append all documents in directory into a single 'document' (list)
for doc in listing:
    doc_name = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\aschein\\My Documents\\comments\\" + doc
    input = open(doc_name).read() 
    input = input.split()
    corpus.append(input)

#Turn list into Text form for NLTK
corpus_text = nltk.Text(corpus)

#Remove stop-words
for w in corpus_text:
    if w in stopwords:
        corpus_text.remove(w)

fd = FreqDist(corpus_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts that I hope at least contribute to an answer.

First, the documentation for the nltk.text.Text() method states (emphasis mine):

> A wrapper around a sequence of simple (string) tokens, which is **intended to support initial exploration of texts (via the interactive console)**. Its methods perform a variety of analyses on the text's contexts (e.g., counting, concordancing, collocation discovery), and display the results. **If you wish to write a program which makes use of these analyses, then you should bypass the Text class, and use the appropriate analysis function or class directly instead.**

So I'm not sure Text() is the way you want to handle this data. It seems to me you would do just fine to use a list.

Second, I would caution you to think about the calculation you're asking NLTK to perform here. Removing stopwords before determining a frequency distribution means that the your frequencies will be skewed; I do not understand why the stopwords are removed before tabulation rather than just ignored in examining the distribution after the fact. (I suppose this second point would make a better query/comment than part of an answer, but I felt it worth pointing out that the proportions would be skewed.) Depending on what you intend to use the frequency distribution for, this may or may not be a problem in and of itself.

Comment: dmh is exactly right. There's no need to use the `text()` function in NLTK. Your `corpus[]` array, as it is, should be fine for performing a FreqDist.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you try to use a list as a hash key. Can you convert it to a tuple?